# How to structure "lib" in Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

In Java, the most acceptable manner of referencing JAR files that are project-specific is from a *lib* folder at the root of the project.  Example: A project is written as a service which references a JAR file that communicates with the actual endpoint.  That JAR file is not stored in "External Libraries".  It is stored in a *lib* folder at the root of the project with many other jars that are used by the project.

What is the most accepted convention of storing external JAR files within a Spring Boot application?  Same?  Different?

Comment: The most accepted way is to use maven or gradle, not to handle this yourself.

Comment: Better use maven or gradle to handle the dependent jars and versioning. To manage your own custom jars, you can setup your artifactory repository. I.e. JFrog Artifactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've done exactly as you describe with spring-boot with an unusual jar dependency that could not be uploaded to a repo because of vendor licensing issues. The jar was copied into the `lib` directory at the project root and referenced in gradle like this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: "lib", include: ["the-jar-filename.jar"])
```

We've had no issues with this solution.

Comment: Thank you!  This fixed all related errors i was experiencing!